# repeating text after using opendir/readdir functions

Tags: php

its a mystery to me why this is happening. so here is the code:

```
$dir = 'test/';
$de = opendir($dir);
if ($de) {
    while (($file = readdir($de)) !== false) {
        $path = $dir . $file;
        $file_title = 'this text gets repeated three times, each followed by a dot' . $file;
        echo $file;
    }
} else {
    echo "invalid directory";
}
```

so If $file= video.mp4 and $file_title='file name'.$file; it would look like this:

'file name.file name.file namevideo.mp4' and if there were no string before the variable, ie $file_title=$title there would be three dots before the variable like this: ...video.mp4

if anyone has any idea what's happening please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Please format you code and your question in general so it is readable.

Comment: glob() then use its array my be easier for you.

Comment: Provide minimum readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are listing the `.` and `..` directories, use [`is_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) to check so the entry is really a file and not a directory:

```
if (is_file($dir . $file)) {
   // entry is a file
}
```

Here you can read more about the `dot` directories: [There's a lot in the dot](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7735/)

Answer (score 2):

You get repeating text because your code contains a loop. That's what `while` does: it runs code repeatedly.